# Padrão de HTTP request

Tags: node.js, restful

Estou desenvolvendo uma API restFull.

Tenho essa rota: `/senha`

No `POST` eu salvo a senha;

No `PUT` eu atualizo a senha;

No `DELETE` eu deleto a senha;

No `GET` eu chamo a senha;

Só que ao usar o `GET` além de chamar, eu atualizo um campo modificando o `status` da mesma.

Só que eu preciso de outro método para poder chamar novamente a senha, mas desta vez sem atualizar o status.

Qual seria o `HTTP` método mais indicado para isso?

Answer (score 0):

Para o seu caso, utilize outra rota/requisição `GET`. Note que a descrição técnica de cada um dos verbos deixa bem clara as suas funções, e levando isso em consideração, o `GET` é o tipo de chamada para ser usada quando a necessidade envolve apenas a requisição e a obtenção de dados sem precisar que o servidor receba algum dado ou configuração do cliente, como é o seu caso, já que não haverá uma atualização de status e nenhum envio de dados, apenas a "rechamada".

Mais detalhes sobre `GET` e os demais verbos http e boas práticas de uso [nesse link da w3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você além de buscar os dados está atualizando um campo no backend, é isso ou entendi errado ? se for o caso você pode usar o método PATCH que é utilizado nos casos onde é feita uma atualização parcial dos dados, diferenciando-se do put onde é enviado para atualização o objeto por completo, no patch envia-se só os dados que serão modificados.